# How to update one table with values from another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table1 with user-information and a table2 with posts made by the users. Sometimes (and only sometimes) it happens that a post is created in Table2 without the user's postal code. I need to find the posts where the ex postal code is missing and then update them with the postal code from table1. 
In both tables I can use 'email' for reference. The first part is easy with:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT` email` FROM `ads` WHERE` postal_code` = '0' "))     {     
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email); 
while($stmt->fetch())
{
// here I would like to do the postal code update,  but it won't do         
}     
$stmt->close();
}
```

How do I get on with the second part of the project: updating the current record in Table2 "?

Comment: What part is unclear for you: how to select the user info based on email or how to update the post?

Comment: The second part: How do I update the current record in Table2 with values ​​from Table1? 
I can search for the postal code in table1 via email which I retrieved in table2.

Comment: Just a regular UPDATE query. What's the problem with it?

Comment: I first have to get the postal code by searching via email and then do update. I don't really know how the update-string should look like in php.

Comment: So the question is how to do an UPDATE query with mysqli? Here you go: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/update

Comment: I know how to make an update, but value must be extracted from another table. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: But you kust said you can do a SELECT query that would "extract" any required value. So I just don't get it what the problem is

Comment: I have solved the problem